# Javascript method not working from external stylesheet - Electron

Tags: javascript, html, methods, electron, electron-builder

I am trying to call a javascript function which is determined by an onclick tag linked with a button. However, the javascript method call seems it is not working. The javascript is external, thus I am not using any inlines scripts.

I am also tyring to store a value from the button from one electron window to another, to store it on localstorage without the use of PHP. The other html Page is "c_card_prepaid_bank.html"

The context here is allowing the user to select an amount to pay.

HTML Main Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/indexStyle.css" />
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form class="grid-container" action="c_card_prepaid_bank.html">
            <button id="set10" class="amnt-btn def-text">€ 10</button>
            <button id="set15" class="amnt-btn def-text">€ 15</button>
            <button id="set20" class="amnt-btn def-text">€ 20</button>
            <button id="set40" class="amnt-btn def-text">€ 40</button>
            <button id="set50" class="amnt-btn def-text">€ 50</button>
        </form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/renderer.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

HTML c_card_prepaid_bank.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/indexStyle.css" />
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bottomText row-cont center-cont">
     <h2 id="preAmount"></h2>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/renderer.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I am using a Javascript method to print out the related amount in h2 ("preAmount")

Javascript Utilities.js

```
//Get Amount in Euros
document.getElementById("set10").onclick = getA();

function getA() {
    localStorage.setItem('pre', "10");
}

const a = localStorage.getItem('pre');
document.getElementById("preAmount").innerHTML = "Credit Amount: " + a;
```

By doing this, nothing comes up in H2

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
document.getElementById('set10').addEventListener("click", function() {
   localStorage.setItem('pre', "10");
}​);​

const a = localStorage.getItem('pre');
document.getElementById("preAmount").innerHTML = "Credit Amount: " + a;
```

Using event listens is typically better than using "onclick" because onclick can be overrided by other event listeners on the page.

Comment: Nothing comes up in <h2 id="preAmount">. However, when I just put:

localStorage.setitem('pre', "10");

it works.